# how to cache symfony partial in memcache?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, memcached, symfony-1.4

We are using symfony 1.4 on our development machine

traditional way to cache partial in symfony is by editing cache.yml

```
something:
  enabled: true
  lifetime: true
```

this will store cache on the disk

but we want to store cache on memcache instead on disk.

so, the question is **how to cache symfony partial in memcache**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony partial cache work like all other cache in symfony: it refers to `view_cache` part of `apps/frontend/config/factories.yml`.

For example, if you want to store your cache in SQLite database:

```
all:
  view_cache:
    class: sfSQLiteCache
    param:
      database: %SF_TEMPLATE_CACHE_DIR%/cache.db
```

So if you want to store these information into Memcached, you should use the `sfMemcacheCache.class.php` class:

```
all:
  view_cache:
    class: sfMemcacheCache
    param:
      servers:
        server1:
          host: localhost
          port: 11211
          persistent: true
```

OR

```
all:
  view_cache:
    class: sfMemcacheCache
    param:
      host: localhost
      port: 11211
      persistent: true
```